# Cannot install dotnet-sdk-2.1 using Fedora 32

Tags: .net, build, sdk, fedora

I have a huge problem on my new fedora-32. I have sucessfully installed dotnet-sdk-3.1, which works fine. But I have a client with web application using dotnet 2.1. So when I try to compile it.

I get

```
/home/****/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design/2.1.2/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(121,5): error : rzc generate exited with code 150. [/home/****/repositories/project/web.csproj]
```

Which should be caused by not installed dotnet core 2.1.

I have try to install dotnet-sdk-2.1 by

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

but I get

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:14:45 ago on Thu 02 Jul 2020 09:12:06 AM CEST.
No match for argument: dotnet-sdk-2.1
Error: Unable to find a match: dotnet-sdk-2.1
```

so I have tried to add microsoft repo by

```
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft-prod.repo https://packages.microsoft.com/config/fedora/32/prod.repo
```

then I'm able to install dotnet-sdk-2.1 but when I'm trying to build my app I still get

```
/home/****/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design/2.1.2/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets(121,5): error : rzc generate exited with code 150. [/home/****/repositories/project/web.csproj]
```

Please help I need to work for my client and I cannot even build the app :/